# How to handle listView item changes in managed option menu dialogs?

Tags: android

I create a dialog in my activities `onCreateDialog` method like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items);
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.dialogTitle).setAdapter(adapter,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // do something
            }
        }).create();
```

The items I want to show in the dialog are in a simple ArrayList

```
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The dialog is now managed (saved and restored) by my activity - as I understand. Thus it is not recreated every time the user presses the menu button to open the dialog.

According to some user selection on the activity - the item list of the dialog needs to be changed. I thought this would be no great problem but after changing the content of the list I run into the following exception:

```
06-03 10:55:29.263: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. 
Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, 
but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908785, class com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
```

I debugged the `Thread.currentThread().getId()` and found it always to be "1" (creation of the dialog and also changing the items list).

How can I handle the item list changes to be noticed by my dialog? Or should I avoid using a "managed" dialog and create it from scratch every time the user opens it?

How can/should I make things work?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange() is enabled, or properly call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after data change.

Answer (score 0):

Reading you, I get a feeling like you're not properly saving/restoring something with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState().`

When an activity is paused and resumed, the view hierarchy of managed dialogs is automatically saved and restored. That obviously includes the `ListView`.

But if the adapter state and/or data is not restored to its previous state, then the `ListView` may detect an unconsistency between it's own (restored) state and the attached adapter. For instance, I can imagine problems if the number of items in the adapter changes after pause/resume.

This could be coherent with the error message you get, something has changed in the adapter but the `ListView` did not get noticed, except that this may be caused by inconsistent state saving/restoring as I explain, instead of a threading issue.

Make sure that you properly save and restore the state of the adapter.

Comment: I do not pause the activity - so I do not go through `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState`. The user just selects a different _parent_ item in the activity and I need to show a different _child_ item list in the option menu dialog. At the moment I create a new `Adapter` for the dialogs ListView and pass it through the ListView in `onPrepareDialog`. So I do not have to create a new dialog - but I thought the existed Adapter should have noticed data changes itself and notify the ListView. Nevertheless thanks for response.

Comment: I see, I got confused by the sentence which mentions "saved and restored". I'm pretty sure that the dialog runs in the main UI thread, this error message is misleading IMO. Do you have   `ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange()` set to true, or properly call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after data change? If this problem persist, I would personally try with a custom `Adapter`, by subclassing `BaseAdapter`. It's very easy, more flexible, and would avoid some `ArrayAdapter` "magic".

Comment: `ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange()` and `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` did what I was looking for. If you update your answer I will accept it! Thanks for support!

Comment: Good! I've added another answer instead of updating my first answer, to avoid confusion.